# java.security.cert.CertificateParsingException

Tags: java, security, certificate, x509certificate, x509certificate2

I'm getting the following exception when trying to create a new certificate:

java.security.cert.CertificateParsingException: signed overrun, bytes = 224

```
    try
    {
        InputStream certificateStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(certificate);
        CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
        Collection certificateCollection = cf.generateCertificates(certificateStream);
    }
    catch (CertificateException ex)
    {

    }
```

the exception is thrown in:
Collection certificateCollection = cf.generateCertificates(certificateStream);

can someone help me to understand and solve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Put the whole code.Where is this `certificate` coming from?Is it a valid certificate?

Comment: you could try a `new FileInputStream("stackoverflow.cert");` instead of using a byte array. I've tried your example on my side with a FileInputStream and a valid certificate file, and it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, my mistake.

I read the certificate from file, and I didn't read it as binary...

Reading as binary solved this issue.

Thanks alot for all your answers / comments!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a [well-functioning example based on your code](https://bitbucket.org/jrx/jrxpublic/downloads/11959576.zip). It uses a `FileInputStream`. If you use a ByteArray, be careful of the data within it :

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.security.cert.CertificateFactory;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class StackOverflow {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, CertificateException {
        InputStream certificateStream = new FileInputStream("stackoverflow.cert");
        CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
        Collection certificateCollection = cf.generateCertificates(certificateStream);
    }
}
```